# Find two records in the table that have the same value

Tags: mysql

I have a table `b_im_message`. It has columns `id`, `chat_id`, `user_id`. I can’t create a query so that in column "user_id" there were 3 or 4 values, and in column `chat_id` there were two entries. It is difficult to describe. I will show an example.

Initial table view

```
mysql> select id, chat_id, user_id from b_im_relation;
+----+---------+---------+
| id | chat_id | user_id |
+----+---------+---------+
| 11 |       6 |       1 |
| 12 |       6 |       3 |
| 13 |       7 |       1 |
| 14 |       7 |       4 |
| 16 |       8 |       1 |
| 15 |       8 |       3 |
| 18 |       9 |       1 |
| 17 |       9 |       4 |
| 19 |      10 |       3 |
| 20 |      11 |       3 |
| 21 |      11 |       4 |
+----+---------+---------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Select lines with a value of 3 or 4 and any "chat_id"

```
mysql> SELECT id, chat_id, user_id 
       FROM b_im_relation 
       WHERE user_id IN (3,4) and  
             EXISTS(SELECT id, chat_id, user_id 
                    FROM b_im_relation t1 
                    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                  FROM b_im_relation t2 
                                  WHERE t1.chat_id=t2.chat_id and 
                                  t1.id<>t2.id));
+----+---------+---------+
| id | chat_id | user_id |
+----+---------+---------+
| 12 |       6 |       3 |
| 15 |       8 |       3 |
| 19 |      10 |       3 |
| 20 |      11 |       3 |
| 14 |       7 |       4 |
| 17 |       9 |       4 |
| 21 |      11 |       4 |
+----+---------+---------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Selected pair "chat_id"

```
mysql> SELECT id, chat_id, user_id 
       FROM b_im_relation t1 
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b_im_relation t2 
                     WHERE t1.chat_id=t2.chat_id and 
                              t1.id<>t2.id) and 
             EXISTS (SELECT id, chat_id, user_id 
                     FROM b_im_relation 
                     WHERE user_id in (3,4));
+----+---------+---------+
| id | chat_id | user_id |
+----+---------+---------+
| 11 |       6 |       1 |
| 12 |       6 |       3 |
| 13 |       7 |       1 |
| 14 |       7 |       4 |
| 16 |       8 |       1 |
| 15 |       8 |       3 |
| 18 |       9 |       1 |
| 17 |       9 |       4 |
| 20 |      11 |       3 |
| 21 |      11 |       4 |
+----+---------+---------+
```

I need this:

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id | chat_id | user_id |
+----+---------+---------+
| 20 |      11 |       3 |
| 21 |      11 |       4 |
+----+---------+---------+
```

Any value "id", any same value "cat_id" and '3' or '4' in "user_id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `chat_id`s where `user_id`s 3 and 4 are in:

```
select i.*
from b_im_relation i inner join (
    select chat_id
    from b_im_relation
    where user_id in (3,4)
    group by chat_id
    having count(distinct user_id) = 2
) t on t.chat_id = i.chat_id
```

If you want the `chat_id`s where only `user_id`s 3 and 4 are in:

```
select i.*
from b_im_relation i inner join (
    select chat_id
    from b_im_relation
    group by chat_id
    having count(distinct user_id) = 2 and sum(user_id not in(3, 4)) = 0
) t on t.chat_id = i.chat_id
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table 'i'

Answer (score 0):

Find all the user/chat combinations with multiple records, then join to get all such records:

```
select id, chat_id, user_id
from (
    select chat_id, user_id
    from b_im_relation
    where user_id in (3,4)
    group by chat_id, user_id
    having count(*) > 1
) multiple_chats
natural join b_im_relation
```